# How long does a bearer token last?

Tags: google-translate

I don't see any details on the lifetime of a bearer token in the Google docs. Is it configurable?

It's strange that the google cloud API is required to obtain a token. I don't want to package any google jars with my app. I just want to use Rest to access the translator. So if the token expires how do I get another one?

Thanks